# How to use `jq` to obtain the keys

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing, jq

My json looks like this :

```
{
  "20160522201409-jobsv1-1": {
    "vmStateDisplayName": "Ready",
    "servers": {
      "20160522201409 jobs_v1 1": {
        "serverStateDisplayName": "Ready",
        "creationDate": "2016-05-22T20:14:22.000+0000",
        "state": "READY",
        "provisionStatus": "PENDING",
        "serverRole": "ROLE",
        "serverType": "SERVER",
        "serverName": "20160522201409 jobs_v1 1",
        "serverId": 2902
      }
    },
    "isAdminNode": true,
    "creationDate": "2016-05-22T20:14:23.000+0000",
    "totalStorage": 15360,
    "shapeId": "ot1",
    "state": "READY",
    "vmId": 4353,
    "hostName": "20160522201409-jobsv1-1",
    "label": "20160522201409 jobs_v1 ADMIN_SERVER 1",
    "ipAddress": "10.252.159.39",
    "publicIpAddress": "10.252.159.39",
    "usageType": "ADMIN_SERVER",
    "role": "ADMIN_SERVER",
    "componentType": "jobs_v1"
  }
}
```

My key keeps changing from time to time. So for example `20160522201409-jobsv1-1` may be something else tomorrow. Also I may more than one such entry in the json payload.

I want to `echo $KEYS` and I am trying to do it using `jq`.

Things I have tried : 
`| jq .KEYS` is the command i use frequently.

Is there a jq command to display all the primary keys in the json?

I only care about the `hostname` field. And I would like to extract that out. I know how to do it using `grep` but it is NOT a clean approach.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to know that key, rather than just directly querying through to the things underneath it?

Comment: (BTW, an all-caps shell variable name such as `$KEYS` is bad form; the POSIX spec for environment variables specifies that it's the namespace of *lower-case* names reserved for application use; since shell variables and environment variables share a namespace, following this convention avoids collisions. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html)

Comment: I am interested in the hostname, and i dont care about the keys. And I can have multiple entries in the json.

Comment: Ahh! Going straight to the hostnames is easy. :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can simply use: `keys`:

```
% jq 'keys' my.json
[
  "20160522201409-jobsv1-1"
]
```

And to get the first:

```
% jq -r 'keys[0]' my.json
20160522201409-jobsv1-1
```

`-r` is for raw output:

> `--raw-output / -r:` With this option, if the filter’s result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.

[Source](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

If you want a known value below an unknown property, eg `xxx.hostName`:

```
% jq -r '.[].hostName' my.json
20160522201409-jobsv1-1
```

Comment: You might also mention how to get, say, an `ipAddress` without knowing the top-layer key.

Comment: You have the right idea, but I think the OP is actually looking for `jq -r 'keys[]' my.json`.

Comment: ...actually, the OP has clarified in the comments on the question: "I am interested in the hostname, and [I] don't care about the keys"; thus it would be `.[].hostName` of interest.